# mdadm - Convert multiple md members from RAID 5 to RAID 6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I've been looking for resources to manage a migration of several md members from RAID 5 to RAID 6 using mdadm.

Using this handy guide, http://www.ewams.net/?date=2013/05/02&view=Converting_RAID5_to_RAID6_in_mdadm, I can trace through how to convert one member from RAID 5 to RAID 6. (Details from link added below in case website becomes unavailable)

Single Member migration from RAID 5 to RAID6:

- Step 1: View mdadm status with `cat /proc/mdstat` and detailed information with `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`
- Step 2: If healthy, add additional disk to cover RAID 6 double parity requirements with `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=6 --raid-devices=[number_of_drives] backup-file=/root/raid5backup`
- Step 3: View `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` to verify RAID is rebuilding. Use same command again after rebuild to ensure all drives synced and healthy.

My question is this. If I've separated my swap from my root partition into md0 (swap) and md1 (/) as is shown in the Ubuntu Server Guide under Advanced Installation, how do I convert both md0 and md1 members to RAID 6? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this works.

Example:

You have disk `sda`, `sdb` and `sdc` equally partitioned into `sda/b/c1` and `sda/b/c2`. Your raid `md0` resides on the three partitions `sda/b/c1`, `md1` on `sda/b/c2`.

Now you partition the new disk `sdd` with the same partition scheme. This gives you the partitions `sdd1` and `sdd2`.

Then you add `sdd1` to `md0` and `sdd2` to `md1`. They should apear as spare devices.

Finally you switch the raid level and grow the number of raid disks with `mdadm --grow` command shown in your question. You do it once for `md0` and once form `md1`.